# Getting the same value of the const variable even after changing it through const_cast

Tags: c++

Consider the below code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    const int i=3;
    int *ptr;

    ptr=const_cast<int*>(&i);
    *ptr=5;

    cout<<"i= "<<i<<endl;  <------------------- statement 1
    cout<<"*ptr= "<<*ptr<<endl;  <------------- statement 2

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as:

```
i= 3
*ptr= 5
```

http://ideone.com/Bvme6

Why is the value of `i` is not changed through pointer?

I know casting away the const-ness of a variable which is explicitly declared as const and modifying its value is 'Undefined Behavior'. I am curious to know: Is it any compiler optimization mechanism that 'compiler replaces the variable in the program with the value'?.
It means the statement 1 is interpreted by the compiler as:

```
cout<<"i= "<<3<<endl;
```

Even if the statement

```
ptr=const_cast<int*>(&i);
```

is replaced by

```
 ptr=(int*)(&i);
```

I am getting the same output: http://ideone.com/5lzJA

Comment: If you want to know what the compiler did, just look at what the compiler did (i.e. the generated code).

Comment: I think the downvotes are harsh

Comment: The optimisation is usually referred to as "constant propagation".  The compiler is allowed to do *anything* it likes so long as the observable behaviour is correct. The behaviour is undefined, so the compiler is automatically correct in anything it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it any compiler optimization mechanism that compiler replaces the variable in the program with the value?

Yes; that will be why you don't see the value changing. The behaviour of trying to modify a `const` object is left undefined in order to allow optimisations like that (as well as allowing the objects to be placed in unwritable memory).

Answer (score 1):

It's not an optimization. An optimization is the transformation of a program into another program that has the same behaviour, but uses less resources. Your program does not have any defined behaviour, so you can't possibly apply any transformation to it that yields the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely since it is a const int, the compiler is optimizing and directly replacing it with the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

`i` *could* be stored in a protected area of memory for `ptr` to point to. Of course anything can be the case, which is why it's **undefined** - which basically means don't depend on any particular behaviour occurring if you do try to trigger undefined behaviour.

For all you know it could cause your computer to go into cardiac arrest or start shooting out laser beams, but you never know because it's ... (w a i t _ f o r _ i t) ... **undefined** ;).

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem, I added volatile, now it's modifying:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  volatile const int a=5;
  int *p = const_cast<int*>(&a);
  *p=6;
  cout<<"a="<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a=6
```

volatile tells compiler that the identifier can be modified (if not by this code then by some one else, so do not perform any optimization)